# Get only one entry for columns that have the same id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table 1:

employer(**id_em**, nom_em)

Table 2:

the second one is 
 travailler(**id_em, id_depart, date_chnge**)

a certain **id_em** can have multiple entries in the **travailler** table but I want only to get a table with the latest entry of id_em, so basically the one with the biggest date.

so the result of my query should be something like this :
**(id_em, nom_em, id_depart, date_change)**

but only one entry for every id_em, the one that has the latest date
I've tried this but it shows all of them, I don't know what's wrong

```
SELECT employe.nom_em, 
       travailler.id_em, 
       travailler.id_depart, 
       Max(travailler.date_chnge) 
FROM   employe 
       INNER JOIN travailler 
               ON employe.id_em = travailler.id_em 
GROUP  BY employe.id_em
```

Please help!
[image]
[image]

Comment: To get the most recent entry in the travailler table you could replace 'GROUP BY employe.id_em' with 'ORDER BY date_change DESC LIMIT 1'.

Comment: when I limit the date_change by 1 it only gives me one column as a result, i need one column per id_em

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     e.nom_em, 
     t.id_em, 
     t.id_depart, 
     t.date_chnge
FROM 
    employe e
INNER JOIN 
     travailler t
ON e.id_em=t.id_em 
WHERE
     t.date_chnge = (select max(tr.date_chnge) from travailler tr where tr.id_em = e.id_em)
```